# Parallel connection database data saving with python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to make parallel database saving in my system. I have two destination that the database will be saved. Firstly in the local computer (so I'm using localhost instead of the IPaddress) and the remote PC (i'm using the IP address to access it). Here is my code in python :

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="rooting",db="database") or die ("could not connect to database")
dbConn2 = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.1.132",user="bobi",passwd="rooting",db="database") or die ("could not connect to database")

cursor = dbConn.cursor()
cursor2 = dbConn2.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyACM0'

while 1:
    try: 
        arduino = serial.Serial(device,9600)
    except:
        print "Failed to connect on",device

    try:
        data = arduino.readline()
        try:
            print("Frequency : " + data)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO frequency (Value) VALUES (%s)",(data))
            dbConn.commit()
        except dbConn.IntegrityError:
            print "failed to insert data to localhost"

        try:
            cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO frequency (Value) VALUES (%s)",(data))
            dbConn2.commit()
        except dbConn2.IntegrityError:
            print "failed to insert data to remote computer"

    except:
        print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

I want to ignore the dbConn2 althought the connection is not connect. The connection is using ethernet LAN. So when I unplug the LAN, I hope my program still running (still send to localhost).
The result of my code above is when i'm unplugging the ethernet LAN, data sending to localhost has stopped. I try to make changes but still get the problem. I'm using python 2.7. I need your help, thank you :)

Comment: This question is far too broad. You need to do several things. 1) Commit frequently to avoid losing work. 2) You probably want to set things up so that data loaded to local host is loaded to the other DB *later*. 3) Handle the exception that bubbles up when the remote connection fails. (What do you want to happen? Should it try to establish a new connection, just give up on the remote connection entirely? There's lots of options.)

Comment: If sending data to the remote server on the fly isn't necessary, I wouldn't even put it in this program. I'd write a separate program or query to load the data to the remote server, and you could run it when you have time to let it run (i.e., when you're *not* going to unplug the thing). Alternatively, consider the simple solution: **don't disconnect your network while this is running**; you may need to buy a longer ethernet cable or switch to wireless or something.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yea it's true. But I predict the real situation in my area. The remote computer is far away from the server and sometimes the network for this remote computer get disturbance. I just think that if the disturbance occurs, the program still store the data measurements to the localhost only. I need some condition code to solve this..

Comment: No, you don't need conditional code. You need *replication*. Store it all locally the first time, and port it over after it is safely stored locally. What solution you use to do that depends on the situation. Database synchronization tools might be helpful. If not, then write you own uploader and design it to be able to stop and restart at will. (It's okay to do small batches, as long as it can tell what's been moved and what hasn't.) But keep it separate from where you save it the first time; trying to combine these into a single program will only give you heartburn in the long run.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ohh so the solution is making two program. First program is for storing to localhost. Second program is for the remote computer. Is the arduino serial port can do it? I mean two programs at same time take the serial result. So it cant be combined right?  If you can combine it, please edit my code above maybe, i just making many alternatives from that code still have the problem..

Comment: No, the second program should pull from the local database, where the first program stored it earlier.

Comment: @jpmc26 can you help me how to make the program that can get from the local host and send it to the remote computer? im thinking that it will copy all the database in local to remote computer, including the same value, so it will be bad..

Comment: Yes, inserting new copies of existing data into the remote database is bad. You're basically doing synchronization. You should look to see if you can find existing tools that do this before you write your own. (Fortunately, your data is read only, so you don't have to worry about updating changed data.) If you do have to write your own, you'll need a unique identifier in the local host database, and you'll need to match those up against the remote database somehow to only load the new ones.